# Only 1 Jquery UI Multiselect value being sent through PHPmailer

Tags: php, jquery, user-interface, phpmailer, multi-select

I am working on a contact form that is not posting my multiple selection answers correctly.  I am using PHPMailer-FE to send the form results.    PHPMailer-FE contains a php class file, configuration script, and TPL file.

I am encountering a problem with Ryan Cramer's jquery.amselect.js widget where the word "Array" is being sent in the email instead of a comma separated list of selected values.

Here is an example of the amselect widget in action:
http://www.ryancramer.com/projects/asmselect/examples/example1.html.

Here's the HTML:

```
   <select style="width: 200px !important;" id="cards" name="cards[]" multiple="multiple" title="Choose All That Apply" >
            <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
            <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
            <option value="Amex">American Express</option>
            <option value="Discover">Discover</option>
            <option value="Diners">Diner's Club</option>
            <option value="JCB">JCB</option>
            <option value="Visa-Delta">Visa Debit/Delta</option>
            <option value="Switch-Maestro">Switch/Maestro</option>
            <option value="solo">solo</option>
            <option value="Visa-Electron">Visa Electron</option>
          </select>
```

Thanks to @aSeptik, I now understand to fix the issue we can use the implode tag.  In his working demo the php is included at the top of the HTML file:

```
$message .= implode(', ',$_POST['cards']);
```

I have tried using the implode tag in my TPL or class file with no success.

Any assistance would be much appreciated I am working very hard to fix this problem.   Many thanks!  Regards, Nolan

Comment: i have updated with a demo let's try it. ;)

Comment: Take a look at my project slimmed down just to show only the multiselect.. [Different Multiselect](http://modsweblog.com/sifdemo/demo.html)   Can someone please tell me why only the first value is being sent?!    Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** *( PHPMailer-FE + amselect Example )*

> - **Demo + Source:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/only-1-jquery-ui-multiselect-value-being-sent-through-phpmailer

Comment: aSeptik. Thanks for the demo although I was actually referring to eric hynds' multiselect widget, same name with notable differences from what you provided.   Take a look at my project slimmed down just to show the multiselect.. [Different Multiselect](http://modsweblog.com/sifdemo/demo.html)   MANY THANKS.

Comment: @Nolan: i have updated the demo and the source test it download it ;)

Comment: @aSeptik:   using a different select widget now, the last one was buggy.  The new select tool works great but when I get the email all that is listed is the word "Array".   Could you PLEASE take a look at this and let me know what you think:  http://jsfiddle.net/WFgnn/

Comment: @Nolan: i have updated the demo and the source! download it again and look into the code. btw, this time, **whould be nice if you want to check the answer** for the sake! ;) thank's.

Comment: Thanks so much Aseptik.  Nice work.  I see the implode tag does it..    I will add this snippet to the question because I am still encountering a problem-  your example works fine haha..  but getting it in my project has been challenging.   Can I add the implode tag into the TPL file, into the html page,  or do I need to add it somewhere inside the PHPMailer Class file?

Comment: @Nolan: updated once again. download and look into the source. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is caused by incorrectly naming your inputs. I haven't used multi select before but I would sudggest that your input tags need to look something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myBox[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myBox[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myBox[]" />
```

etc...

Notice that you need to have square brackets for array notation in the name attribute. PHP will show the variable as an array if you do that.

In your case (now you've added an example) You just need to make your select tag have the array operator at the end:

```
<select class="mydrop" name="cards-accepted[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
</select>
```

Comment: I added the HTML code above.   Should I assign the same name to each of the options?

Comment: No, just change the name of your <select /> tag:
<select class="mydrop" name="cards-accepted[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at the plugin you said you were using and I now see what the problem is... it's buggy.

The inputs it generates are no good for posting to a server because they all have the same name. PHP has no way of distinguishing between inputs with the same name (unless they include the bracket notation - [] - then they are treated as arrays)

I mocked up a little demo here:

http://jsbin.com/upuhe/edit

Use something like firebug to inspect the checkboxes and you will see that they all have the same name.

If I where you I would use JQuery to rename the chekboxes that your plugin creates like this:

see: http://jsbin.com/upuhe/2/edit

```
$("select").multiselect()
  .each(function(){

    var selectEl = $(this);        
    var selectElName = selectEl.attr("name")

    selectEl.multiselect("widget")
      .find("input[type=checkbox]")
        .attr({ name: selectElName });
})
```

This assumes you set your select something up like `<select name='select[]' multiple='multiple'>`